# Add data validation to a table from a 3D array, VBA excel

Tags: vba, excel

I've got a 3D array of strings, myArray(1 to 30,1 to 80,1 to 20). In my workbook I have a table that occupies the range (1,1) to (30,20).
I want to use the **validation.add type method** to validate the cells of the table in the following order:

**the 1st column of the table**:

cell(1,**1**) should contain the values myArray(1,1,**1**) to myArray(1,80,**1**)

cell(2,**1**) should contain the values myArray(2,1,**1**) to myArray(2,80,**1**)

...

cell(30,**1**) should contain the values myArray(30,1,**1**) to myArray(30,80,**1**)

**the 2nd column of the table**:

cell(1,**2**) should contain the values myArray(1,1,**2**) to myArray(1,80,**2**)

cell(2,**2**) should contain the values myArray(2,1,**2**) to myArray(2,80,**2**)

...

cell(30,**2**) should contain the values myArray(30,1,**2**) to myArray(1,80,**2**)

**and so on..**

In short, each cell in the table should contain drop lists with data extracted from the array (each column of the table contains values from a different page of the array).

I apologize if my question isn't well specified, I'm new to programing and have little experience with VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following simplified solution demonstrates adding the Validation `DropDown` List to the `Worksheet` `Cell` "A1" based on the Array `List1` values:

```
Sub AddValidation()
    Dim List1(1 To 5) As String
    List1(1) = 1
    List1(2) = 2
    List1(3) = 3
    List1(4) = 4
    List1(5) = 5

    With Range("A1").Validation
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:=Join(List1, ",")
        .InCellDropdown = True
    End With
End Sub
```

In order to dynamically modify the validation list added to Worksheet `Cells`, refer to the solution shown below:

```
Sub AddValidationDynamicList()
    Dim List1(1 To 5) As String
    List1(1) = 1
    List1(2) = 2
    List1(3) = 3
    List1(4) = 4
    List1(5) = 5

    Dim str As String
    str = Join(List1, ",")

    For I = 1 To 5
        With Range("A" & I).Validation
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:=str
            .InCellDropdown = True
        End With
        str = Mid(str, InStr(1, str, ",") + 1)
    Next I
End Sub
```

You can further extend this solution pertinent to your requirements of using multidimensional array.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Seems that this will do the trick. Only one more thing I still can't figure: how do I use join() for only part of an array? say the first column

Comment: This sample solution creates the string by applying the Join() function to the entire array, then removing string parts iteratively. Alternatively, you may dynamically re-create array and then apply Join() function. Based on your comments, I would appreciate if you mark the answer accepted. Should you have more questions, please post them separately, include your code snippet and highlight the problematic part. Good luck with your project. Best regards,